# How can i persist view content when state change?

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, nested, view

Is there any way to persist content from named ui-view when i change the state ? I really need it to do a multiple window behaviour.

Here is the plunker, when clicking main 3 or main 4 i want to persist the content.

```
<div>
<div id="mainNav" ui-view="mainNav"></div>
<div id="subNav" ui-view="subNav"></div>
<div id="content" ui-view="content"></div>
```

[here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t5k8AdVojM8PvwPBES27?p=preview)

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for everyone who is facing this problem the solution is using sticky:true, this will keep your named ui-views persist.

```
state('group.overview', {
    url : "/overview",
    views:  {
        'overview@group': {
            controller: 'timerController',
            template: '<h1>Overview</h1><div scope-age></div>'
        }
    },
 sticky: true,
 deepStateRedirect: true
```

Is an apy from 
[Documentation here](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)

[Codepen working here](http://codepen.io/stempler/pen/zxObpN)

Notice that if you erase sticky:true it wont persist the named view, so its working nice.

Hope it helps :)